# Does ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory increases parallelism in consumption of messages from Kafka Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have always read that Kafka **only assigns one consumer instance (thread) to a single partition**. I recently came across **ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory** and was reading on it, and some aspects seemed contradictory to what I Knew before.

Let's say we have one consumer instance (pod/machine) and within it I use **ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory with concurrency level set to three 3** . I have a Kafka Topic with three partitions. With concurrency level set to three I understand my **@KafkaListener method will read messages from all three partitions of the topic** .

Does this mean that even with one consumer instance we are able to consume messages from three partitions in parallel.

Can this be used as a substitute to increase rate of consumption  from a Kafka topic without increasing the number of partitions. The only other way I knew was to create a thread pool and submit the received messages to it . **Can we use ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory as a replacement for this process as this definitely sounds much easier to implement** .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainer` creates the number of `KafkaConsumer` instances according your configuration . That’s how you can read different partitions in parallel .

Don’t mix a `KafkaConsumer` object with a general consumer entity definition. In other words your consumer application is definitely not a Kafka Consumer object by Apache Kafka definition. This is not a first time though I hear that people call their application as “Kafka Consumer”… what doc did you read that makes you think so ?

See more info about concurrency in Spring for Apache Kafka in its docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#message-listener-container

Comment: Thanks. So from what I understand my application has as many consumer instances within it as the concurrency level of ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainer. This basically means in case of a three partition topic and three consumer application instances with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainer concurrency set to three - we actually have 9 consumer instances thread and only three of them will get used ?

Comment: Correct. That’s the point of consumer group

Comment: @ArtemBilan I have one confusion
suppose we have 3 partitions and 3 consumer instances, increasing consumer instances can be helpful or not in handling load and scaling.
if not what are the ways to handle the scale other then increasing the kafka partitions.

Comment: It is not recommended by the Kafka ordering feature to consume same partition concurrently. There is an offset which has to be committed and it effects subsequent records consuming in new consumers in a group. Therefore the best performance is a consumer per partition. And this is the way Spring for Apache Kafka follows with its concurrency option.